# Disable SSL for Google in Firefox

Tags: firefox, ssl, ssl-certificate, google-search

Since a couple of weeks I'm having problems with Google (Firefox 47.0 x64), specific with the SSL certificate. Every time I'm tried to load a Google page: Gmail, Search, Plus, Maps, Wallet, PlayStore from PC, etc. Firefox throw me the error page that my connection isn't secure that cannot skipe, so I can't load any Google page. The error is: **SEC_ERROR_UNKNOWN_ISSUER**

This happens me only in Firefox, I already tried load a Google page from Opera and everything is Ok, no problem! The issue is in Firefox.

I would prefer post this in Firefox support forums, but... as I can investigate, Firefox is Ok and officialy, they have no problems or known issues with Google's SSL Certificate. So, looks like the problem is from my side (don't understand how?).

I need to use Google services, so: How can I disable (by brute force) the use of SSL in Google page in my Firefox?

This problem only happened to me in Google page, other pages with SSL works fine!

Comment: You should try to fix the problem rather than circumvent a system designed to protect you. Have you backed up and deleted your Firefox profile? Have you disabled any and all Firefox plugins? Have you uninstalled/reinstalled Firefox? Have you tried to access Google services through Firefox on a different profile on your computer?

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be the build-in certificate store in firefox, while Chrome is using the system certificate store.

In Chrome, go to google.com, click the little lock in the address bar and chose details (in the top). 
In the newly opened bar click view certificate, you should now be able to export it (in OSX which I'm using you can just drag the small certificate into finder). It should be called something like "GeoTrust Global CA.cer"

In Firefox, go to about:preferences#advanced (or preferences, then advanced) and "View certificates" and then "Authorities". Click import and chose the certificate you exported from Chrome.